# Users are getting a temporary profile

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, user-profile

A bit about current setup:

It is windows 2008 R2 AD servers (all of them are 2008R2) and couple locations which set as Sites. Each location has DFS on AD server. Roaming profiles are not used nor configured. Users have their home folder configured as mapped S: drive to DFS shared folder. For example: in profile tab user has: Home Folder -> connect -> S: to `\\domain.com\dc\users\%username%`

We also have redirected Desktop, Documents and Downloads folders to `\\domain.com\dc\users`.

Everything was fine. Suddenly (today), users in most locations lost their local profile (both XP and W7 desktops) and got temporary profiles. Also, it looks like local profile was created today (from folder properties).

I checked events at couple machines and there is not errors related to profiles or logon process. I do not see issues in event logs at servers as well.

Basically, I run out of ideas what is wrong and why machines lost their local profiles.

PS: Laptop users do not have their folders redirected, but lost profiles as well.

Comment: so logged in as a user that has a temp profile directiry do the following "dir \\domain.com\dc\users\%username%" at a command prompt

Comment: Well, all users are using their desktops now, so I cannot try it right now, but explorer can browse all shares and redirected folders normally.

Comment: so the s: drive is mapped correctly?

Comment: had to re-read things, so they only had local profiles correct? If so then maybe permission are screwed up on their old profile.

Comment: Yes, S: drive is mapped correctly. So, if permissions were screwed up - why in all offices?

Comment: With whats being described none of this really makes sense.

Comment: Well, with the profiles being on a DFS share, that provides a mechanism where all the share permissions could be altered at once.  Did someone or something change the inheritable permissions at a level above the profiles' location?

Comment: Ok, got access to desktop. Yes, I can dir \\domain.com\dc\users\%username%

Comment: @HopelessN00b Profiles are local actually as it is just folder redirection, not roaming.

Comment: This is the warning message I got in Application log:  Event Type: Warning
Event Source: Group Policy Drive Maps
Event Category: (2)
Event ID: 4098
Date:  10/19/2012
Time:  3:02:42 PM
User:  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Computer: WKS-MDIAZ
Description:
The user 'G:' preference item in the 'GA Group Policy {608162F7-CB29-47B5-8260-A322BE273708}' Group Policy object did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80070005 Access is denied.' This error was suppressed.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Comment: What bothers me is that one W7 machine cannot create a local profile (there is no profile for that user locally at all) and uses temporary one and not even single word in Event log.

Comment: so at wks-mdias workstation browse the profile directory and check the permissions on the profiles located there.

Comment: check to see if somebody updated the roaming profile section for the users within AD.

Comment: also check the sysvol permissions to verify the permissions there.

Comment: @tonyroth I checked and so far so good - all permissions are fine. Back to the W7 machine - it does not have local profile at all, so permissions could not be broken.

Comment: @tonyroth - I checked all GP polices and they were not updated for month.

Comment: GP has nothing to do with this, also you maybe having problems with you sysvol. Look at the profile settings for these users, did something change.

Comment: @tonyroth - Share permissions: Everyone - readonly, Auth users and Admins full. NTFS permissions: Auth users - read & execute, System - full, Admins - special.

Comment: so on the win7 workstation you only see the user\public folder?

Comment: @tonyroth on the Win 7 desktop in users folder only local Administrator profile, nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution here: http://www.networksteve.com/windows/topic.php/Domain_joined_but_trying_to_log_on_gives_temporary_profile_only/?TopicId=20834&Posts=1

Some one added "Domain Users" group into "Domain Guests" group. That ruined my whole day.

Thanks tony for helping me.

Answer (score 5):

There are several possible reasons for Windows to issue a temporary profile instead of a regular user profile. One of them is that the user logging on is a guest. Others include missing permissions and incorrectly deleted profiles. See this article for a full list:

http://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/11/temporary-user-profiles/

Answer (score 0):

.       Please clear up all the .bak files in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList of the terminal server.

2. Please manually delete these temporary profiles on the terminal server.

Comment: That is unlikely in the extreme to remedy the cause of this problem, though it will temporarily hide it.

Comment: Here's the PowerShell one-liner that will clean up the orphaned keys: `dir 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList'|?{-Not(Test-Path $_.GetValue('ProfileImagePath'))}|%{rm -recurse ($_.Name-replace'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','HKLM:')}`